# XAMPP - ALIAS - Unknown: failed to open stream

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Following instructions from [here](http://www.itsananderson.com/2011/02/creating-xampp-alias-directories/), I have created 2 Alias directories.

```
<Directory "C:\Users\user\Documents\sites">
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /site "C:\Users\user\Documents\sites"

<Directory "S:\directory (servername)\site">
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /lab "S:\directory"
```

When I access `localhost/site` it works fine and loads up the webpage in there.

When I access `localhost/lab` it returns an error.

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'S:/directory (servername)/site/index.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\ProgramData\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

When I did notice in the Properties of `S:\directory (servername)` is that `S:\directory (servername)` PATH is actually `\\servername\directory (servername)` so its being mapped.

How would I go about getting my Alias workign so that I can access `localhost/lab` successfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have S:\directory....

you can just use C:\dir\server\sites, and than in that dir make two folders lab and site!